# NDK with CMake, no file is compiled

Tags: c++, gradle, cmake, android-ndk

The CMakeLists.txt I used is below, I know it is this one, because if I mistype something, an error is printed.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)


set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -u ANativeActivity_onCreate")


set(COMMON_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../common/src")
set(COMMON_HEADERS_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../common/include")
set(GAME_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../game/src")
set(GAME_HEADERS_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../game/include")


#All files that are compiled
file(
  GLOB_RECURSE COMMON_SRCS
  ${COMMON_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cc
  ${COMMON_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp
)
file(
  GLOB_RECURSE GAME_SRCS
  ${GAME_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cc
  ${GAME_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp
)


add_library(
  fc
  ${COMMON_SRCS}
  ${GAME_SRCS}
)
  
target_include_directories(
  fc PUBLIC
  ${COMMON_HEADERS_DIR}
  ${GAME_HEADERS_DIR}
)

target_compile_features(fc PUBLIC cxx_std_20)

target_link_libraries(fc PUBLIC
    log
    android
)
```

And in cmd:

```
#./gradlew assembleDebug

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
34 actionable tasks: 34 executed
```

I have got an apk, but no file of mine is getting compiled, although in
compile_commands.json of cmake folder generated, I can read all the commands to compile my files. I have checked it manually, some commands are working.
So in the cmake folder generating, I can't find any built file of mine.

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.you.fc"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-fexceptions -frtti -std=c++20"
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
                abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
        targetSdk 33
        minSdk 22
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "arm64-v8a"
            universalApk true
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            version "3.27.4"
            path file('CMakeLists.txt')
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '33.0.0'
    ndkPath "/home/me/Desktop/dev/android/android-ndk-r25c/"
    compileSdk 33
    namespace 'com.you.fc'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
}
```

Do you know what is going on ?

Ndk : tested with r26b and r25c
Gradle: tested with 7.5.1 and 8.5
CMake: tested with 3.18 and 3.27
OS: Ubuntu 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `SHARED` to `add_library()` solved the problem.

---

Resource:
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake